# All of the sudden my Dataset won't load -- Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, visual-studio-2010, strongly-typed-dataset

I get a pop-up with this error message every time I open my program:

> Failed to load dataset because of the following error: Object reference not set to an >instance of an object

Every time I try to compile I get errors saying my typed TableAdapter and TableRows don't exist.

When I double click on the data .xsd file to go to the designer view for the dataset I get an error screen with that repeats the Object reference bit and gives me this call stack:

> at >Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsGlobalObjects.SettingsGlobalObjectProvider.CreateGl>obalObjects(Project project)
>   at >Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsGlobalObjects.SettingsGlobalObjectProvider.GetGloba>lObjectsCore(Project project, Type baseType)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.GlobalObjectProvider.GetGlobalObjects(Project >project, Type baseType)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.GlobalObjectService.GetGlobalObjects(Type baseType)
>   at >Microsoft.VSDesigner.VSDesignerPackage.AppSettingsHelper.GetGlobalObjectCollection(IServic>eProvider serviceProvider, Project project)
>   at >Microsoft.VSDesigner.VSDesignerPackage.AppSettingsHelper.AddAppSettingsConnections(IServic>eProvider serviceProvider, Project project, IList connections)
>   at >Microsoft.VSDesigner.VSDesignerPackage.GlobalConnectionService.Microsoft.VSDesigner.VSDesi>gnerPackage.IGlobalConnectionService.GetConnections(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, >Project project)
>   at Microsoft.VSDesigner.DataSource.DesignConnection.GetConnectionFromAppSettings(String >objectName, String propertyName, Project currentProject)
>   at Microsoft.VSDesigner.DataSource.DesignConnection.GetConnectionStringObject(Project >targetProject)
>   at Microsoft.VSDesigner.DataSource.DesignConnection.get_ConnectionStringObject()
>   at Microsoft.VSDesigner.DataSource.DbSource.set_Connection(IDesignConnection value)
>   at Microsoft.VSDesigner.DataSource.DesignDataSource.SetConnectionProperty(Source source)
>   at Microsoft.VSDesigner.DataSource.DesignDataSource.ReadXmlSchema(DataSourceXmlTextReader >xmlReader)
>   at Microsoft.VSDesigner.DataSource.DesignDataSource.ReadXmlSchema(TextReader textReader, >String baseURI)
>   at >Microsoft.VSDesigner.DataSource.Designer.DataSourceSerializationService.DeserializeToDataS>ource(String filePath, Object serializationData)
>   at Microsoft.VSDesigner.DataSource.ProjectDataSourceDescriptor.LoadDataSource()
>   at Microsoft.VSDesigner.DataSource.ProjectDataSourceDescriptor.Init(IServiceProvider >provider, IVsHierarchy primaryHierarchy, UInt32 primaryItemId, Object >primaryDocDataObject, UInt32 docCookie, IVsInvisibleEditor invisibleEditor, IDesignerHost >host)
>   at >Microsoft.VSDesigner.DataSource.ProjectDataSourceStorage.EnsureInvisibleEditor(ProjectItem >dsProjectItem, Boolean ensureWritable, Boolean createInvisibleEditor, Boolean getUIInfo)
>   at Microsoft.VSDesigner.DataSource.ProjectDataSourceStorage.GetDataSourceInternal(Object >caller, ProjectItem dsProjectItem, Boolean ensureWritable, Boolean createInvisibleEditor, >Boolean getUIInfo)
>   at >Microsoft.VSDesigner.DataSource.Designer.DataSourceDesignerLoader.HandleLoad(IDesignerSeri>alizationManager serializationManager)

This program has been working for a while and it just started doing this today. Today I witched the .Net version and then changed it back and altered the installer, but I don't know why any of that would cause this issue. Need some help on this. I'm on a really tight time schedule.

Comment: When you switch the .net version it can change some of the references and not necessarily put them back when you switch the .net version back. Try checking the relevant references are in place.

Comment: I switched the .Net versions back and forth a few times and then I was able to open the Designer for the .xsd file. I 'Congifured' my data sets to have them regenerate the code and that got rid of the errors for the adapters and rows. Violla, it's back to normal. Thanks anyway James. Remind me to wag a finger at Bill Gates next time I see him.

Comment: I think a few people would have words with Bill if they ever met him! Glad you've got things up and running.

Comment: Please answer your own question and mark it as an answer, then other people can benefit, and we don't have the question as unanswered in the lists :)